# Objective C - Using an integer value to identify data in a plist

Tags: objective-c, integer, plist

I would like to start off by saying that I am a bit new to coding in general, but I am excited to learn. I am trying to get a label to cycle through the first four letters of the alphabet, which are stored as strings in a .plist file. The value will switch each time a button is pushed.

Here is the source code of the plist:

```
<dict>
<key>0</key>
<string>A</string>
<key>1</key>
<string>B</string>
<key>2</key>
<string>C</string>
<key>3</key>
<string>D</string>
```

I made the keys integers so that i can easily cycle through the values using the following code:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
int x = 0;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
theLabel_.text = [dict objectForKey:x];
x++;
}
```

This is not working at all. I suspect that the issue is in the line where I change the label's text. I do not believe I am using the "objectForKey" statement correctly with my integer value. How am I supposed to use an integer as a key to access plist data?

Answer (score 0):

Property list dictionaries use strings as keys so you'd have to make strings out of your integer indexes:

```
theLabel_.text = [dict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x]];
```

A better way might be to use an array instead (also a plist object). Then all you'd have to change would be the access method:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
theLabel_.text = [array objectAtIndex:x];
```

Your plist file would look like:

```
<array>
    <string>A</string>
    <string>B</string>
    <string>C</string>
    <string>D</string>
</array>
```